# Change the shape of activated item in BottomNavigation material 3

Tags: android, material-ui, bottomnavigationview, material-you

In the new [BottomNavigation](https://m3.material.io/components/navigation-bar/specs) material 3, we have a default indicator for the active item, that's cool but I wonder if we can custom the shape of that indicator in any way?

[image: Default indicator]

[image: Custom indicator]

Thanks in advance